# Regex (All after first match (without the first match))

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling with the easy Regex expression. Basically I want everything after the first match of "_" without the "_".

My current expression is like this: `_(.*)`

When I give input: `AAA_BBB_CCC`

The output is: `_BBB_CCC`

My ideal output would be: `BBB_CCC`

I am using a snowflake database with their build-in regex function.

Unfortunately, I can not use `(?<=_).*` as it does not support this format of "?<=". Is there some other way how can I modify `_(.*)` to get the right output?

Thank you.

Comment: You just need to get the Group 1 value. What is the programming language?

Comment: I am using the Snowflake SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Snowflake SQL, you may use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html#regexp-substr), its syntax is

> `REGEXP_SUBSTR( <string> , <pattern> [ , <position> [ , <occurrence> [ , <regex_parameters> [ , <group_num ] ] ] ] )`.

The function allows you to return *captured substrings*:

> By default, `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the entire matching part of the subject. However, **if the `e` (for “extract”) parameter is specified, `REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the the part of the subject that matches the first group in the pattern. If `e` is specified but a `group_num` is not also specified, then the `group_num` defaults to 1 (the first group).** If there is no sub-expression in the pattern, REGEXP_SUBSTR behaves as if e was not set.

So, you need to set the *regex_parameters* to `e` and - optionally - `group_num` argument to `1`:

```
Select REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA_BBB_CCC', '_(.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
Select REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA_BBB_CCC', '_(.*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I need to do some Regex course, but for now, it solved my problem. Ones again, thank you.

Comment: when I run your SQL I get the result NULL.

Comment: you need to use the regex_parameter or 'e' to get the matching substring.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Thank you, I added that bit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to achieve this, something like this is JavaScript for example will do the job

```
"AAA_BBB_CCC".replace(/[^_]+./, '')
```

Use REGEXP_REPLACE with Snowflake

```
regexp_replace('AAA_BBB_CCC','^[^_]+_','')
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html

But you can also find the first index of `_` and use substring, available in all languages

```
let text = "AAA_BBB_CCC"
let index = text.indexOf('_')
if(index !== -1 && index < text.length) {
    let result = text.substring(index+1)
}
```

Comment: I'm my snowflake instance, your replace was results in a empty string, I had to use `regexp_replace('AAA_BBB_CCC','^[^_]+_','')` to get the desired result.

Comment: I didn't have Snowflake to test it and forgot the start anchor tag `^`. It's fixed. Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group:

```
\_(?<data>.*)
```

Which returns the capture group `data` containing `BBB_CCC`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/xZaXKR/1

Comment: You should not escape `_`, it is not a special char. Also, if `_(.*)` does not work for OP, why do you think a named group will?

Answer (score 0):

To get this actually working you need to use:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA_BBB_CCC', '_(.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 1);
```

which gives:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA_BBB_CCC', '_(.*)', 1, 1, 'E', 1)
BBB_CCC
```

you need to pass the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html) parameter `<regex_parameters>` clause of `e` as that is `extract sub-matches.` thus Wiktor's answer is 95% correct.